# Prove the surjectivity with intermediate value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $f(x)=x^3-2x+1$ I have to prove the surjectivity with the intermediate value theorem. My idea is:
I know that $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty}f(x)=\pm \infty$ and I want to prove that $\forall s\in \mathbb{R} \exists x : f(x)=s$.
I use the theorem in this following way.
From the limits above I know that:
$\exists B>0 : f(x)>|s| \forall x>B$ and $f(x)<|s| \forall x<-B$.
So let $x_1<-B$ and $x_2>B$ then $f(x_1)<s<f(x_2)$. Now I know that $f(x)$ is continous, but how I can conclude that $\exists x\in [x_1, x_2]$ : $f(x)=s$.

Comment: Start with some $s$ and show that there is some $B$ such that $f(-B) < s$ and $f(B) > s$.

Comment: But it is what I have already done with $x_1$ and $x_2$...right?

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing with $|s|$ above.

Comment: I have written the definition of limits above

Comment: I have only so much energy. Either go back to my first comment or figure out what I am asking in my second. Good luck.

Comment: Three observations:  (1) you do not really need modulus signs around $s$ but in any case you should have written $f(x) < -|s|$ for $x < -B$ (notice the minus sign);  (2) you do not need $x_1$ and $x_2$ since you have $f(-B) < s < f(B)$; (3) the intermediate value theorem *means* that there exists $x \in [-B,B]$ such that $f(x) = s$